# Google "link:" search not working for .zone GTLD domains that have links

Tags: google-search, backlinks

My new .zone domain project (6 months old) "mysite.zone" is having 50+ links, but when searching these links from google with a keyword "link:mysite.zone" there is none returned.  Webmaster tools shows plenty of them.

I quickly tested some other popular .zone sites (e.g. crush.zone) and none seem to return links with "link:" prefix.

Any ideas?

Was the .ZONE domain a bad choice if it has bugs like this or what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's deprecated for all TLD not only to .zone. Only old result are available in serp**

Google does not want to create another database for link operator. It is mainly used by spammer/link buyer in past. So Google does not updating from many years. My website is one year old with .com tld, and it does not display any links when I do search with link operator, while there is some hundred backlinks when I check through Google search console. Only old website will return some of their result.

For your own website Use Google search console tools to check who links to you. For other website use third party tools, normally it's called backlinks checker or analyzer.